# Navigation bar appearance doesn't change after a first setting

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, vertical-alignment, uiappearance

I set a certain vertical offset for the navigation bar's title when the app becomes active:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Then, later in the navigation hierarchy, I need to set a different vertical offset, so I call:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-0.5f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But I find that the new vertical offset is not applied when I navigate being the app active. However, if app becomes inactive and then active again, it is applied. How can I change this offset while the app is kept in foreground?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t
>   change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. **To change
>   the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view
>   from the view hierarchy and then put it back.**

So basically you need to do some HACK to remove the view and then immediately add it back, something like this...

```
UIView *currentview = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window.rootViewController.view;
UIView *superview = currentview.superview;
[currentview removeFromSuperview];
[superview addSubview:currentview];
```

And for Swift...

```
if let currentview = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController?.view {
    if let superview = currentview.superview {
        currentview.removeFromSuperview()
        superview.addSubview(currentview)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing this with animation block?

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:3
             animations:^{
                          [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-3.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
                          [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-0.5f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
                     }];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried and it is neither working... Could it be because I'm testing in iOS 7 and I have to do this in a different way?